Problem displaying GeoJSON data EPSG 4326 in Mapbox
I'm converting data from an S57 file that has an EPSG:4326 projection to GeoJSON, and then adding the data to a Mapbox.
 const ogr2ogrArgs = [
        '-f', 'GeoJSON',
        '-s_srs', 'EPSG:4326',
        '-t_srs', 'EPSG:4326',
        '-sql', `SELECT * FROM ${layerName}`,
        '-dialect', 'SQLITE',
        '/vsistdout/',
        filePath
    ];

I'm seeing a noticeable shift in features.
I don’t understand what’s wrong, since Mapbox should correctly convert EPSG 4326 to EPSG 3857.

